# Do I need to retrain reinforcement model from scratch each time I want to use it in practice?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

This seems like it should be obvious but I can't find resources on it anywhere. I am building a reinforcement learning model with openai's gym any_trading environment and stablebaselines3. There are a ton of online tutorials and documentation for training and evaluating the model but almost nothing on actually using it in practice.

e.g. I want the model constantly looking at `today's` data and making predictions about what action I should take to lock in `tomorrow's` profits.

Reinforcement learning algorithms seem to all have a `model.predict()` method but you have to pass the environment which is just more historical data. What if I want it to use today's data to predict tomorrow's values? Do I just include up to today in the test set and retrain the model from scratch each time I want it to make a prediction?

e.g. Original training data ranges from `2014-01-01 to Today (aka 2023-02-12)` then run through the whole train and testing process? Then tomorrow I start from scratch and train/test using date_ranges `2014-01-01 to Today (aka 2023-02-13)` then the next day `2014-01-01 to Today (aka 2023-02-14)` etc etc? How do I actually make real-time predictions with a Reinforcement Learning model as opposed to continually evaluating how it would have performed on past data?

Thanks.

Comment: if your environment has the same rules and structure (meaning for you if your current dataset relies on the same features as your historical data) that should work. However `predict` is not actually predicting in terms of e.g., LSTM, it is better to unroll this method as "playing with the trained agent on the unseen data within the same environment".

Comment: @gehirndienst, Thank you so much for response. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "playing with the trained agent." Am I incorrect in my understanding that the Agent is using everything it knows about the environment to decide which action to take next? Would that not be the same as prediction? Thanks.

Comment: this "everything it knows" is the result of training -- of the experience collected. And  selecting the next state is not a prediction, it is just a transition with a certain probability depending on your previous iteration (Markov property). An agent doesn't normally know the next state before he finds himself in it, although there are rare cases where you know the whole transition table. There are RL implementations where an agent actually tries to predict the next state BEFORE starting transitioning to it but this is a different story. I suggest you to revise some RL basics and terminology.

Comment: Thanks @gehirndienst. These are good clarifications to clear up some misconceptions I've had about reinforcement learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good and practical question. I assume you use all the history data to train your RL agent in stablebaselines3 in practice and then apply the trained RL agent to predict tomorrow's action. Short answer is NO, you don't need to train your agent from scratch every day.

First you need to understand the procedure in learning and prediction:

In learning or training process:

1. Initialize your RL agent policy or value network.
2. Input the observation on day 2014-01-01 to your RL agent.
3. Your agent makes decisions based on the observation.
4. Calculate your observation and reward/profit on day 2014-01-02 and send them back to your agent.
5. Depend on the RL algorithm you use, your agent might update its policy or value network based on this observation reward pair or it could save this pair into buffer. And only update its policy or value network after certain amount of days (e.g., 30 days, 180 days)
6. repeat step 2-6 until you reach the last day of your database (e.g., 2023-02-12)

In prediction process (which has only procedure 2,3 from training process):

1. Input the observation on day 2014-01-01 to your RL agent.
2. Your agent makes decisions based on the observation.
   That's it.

You can repeated train your model in the training process with the history data until you are satisfied with the performance during the training process. In this retrain process, after each training through the entire history data, you can save the model and load the saved model for the retrain as the initialized model.

Once you get that good model, you don't need to train it anymore with the new coming data after 2023-2-12. It is still valid.

You may think new data is generated everyday and the most recent data is the most valuable one. In this case, you can periodically update your existing model with the new data using following procedure:

1. load your existing RL agent model (the trained model).
2. Input the observation on day one in your most recent new data to your RL agent.
3. Your agent makes decisions based on the observation.
4. Calculate your observation and reward/profit on day two of your new data and send them back to your agent.
5. Depend on the RL algorithm you use, your agent might update its policy or value network based on this observation reward pair or it could save this pair into buffer. And only update its policy or value network after certain amount of days (e.g., 30 days)
6. repeat step 2-6 until you reach the last day of your new data

Comment: Hi @Harry, Thank you so much for detailed explanation. I think the main difference that I need to wrap my head around between say a random forest and reinforcement learning is that a random forest is training in order to give you predictions that you can choose to act on or not whereas reinforcement is an "agent" meaning it acts for itself as it learns. So It's not predicting with the information it gains but rather acting. This has been very helpful in making that distinction. Thanks!